# Black screen after updating to Android Studio 2.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating my Android Studio to version 2.2.1 I can't get my app to display anything except black on the screen of my phone. Before updating it used to work. The app uses OpenGL ES 2.0. It works on an emulator but not on the real device. The app is running, it plays sounds as I touch on the screen, it's just not displaying anything. My phone is Huawei Honor 7.

I've tried everything I can think of such as restarting the phone, deleting the app from the phone, cleaning the project multiple times, manually deleting all the build directories and .iml files, disabling the instant run, building with different gradle versions, testing previous revisions of the app, switching between debug and release builds etc.

What could be causing this?

[image: Black screen on phone]

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what caused this, but what I did to get it working was that I deleted my previous project from Android Studio and made a completely new project with all the new project files stuff that Android Studio created for me, including CMake stuff that didn't exist before, and then copied all the relevant content to it from the previous project. Took one whole day but now at least it works. A lesson learned: Don't update your Android Studio if you're not prepared to spend some time fixing issues. I wish the Android Studio guys had hard of a concept called backwards compatibility...